# Use order by with two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I have two datetime type column and I want to use order by for both column, if anyone is have recent date then it should come on top

I tried the below but it is returning below result which is not as expected.

```
select  *
from v_ServiceHistory
where r_customer = 80
order by r_closed desc, sfh_regeneratedon desc
```

Comment: Any NULL values involved?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Yes, Null value are there in one column for few records but another column will have date and this is  SQLSERVER MANAGEMENT STUDIO 2018

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results

Comment: Sam's is a UI not the database engine. You need `select @@version`

Answer (score 0):

Use a `case` *expression* to get the most recent:

```
order by case when r_closed > sfh_regeneratedon then r_closed 
              else coalesce(sfh_regeneratedon,  r_closed)
         end desc
```

Explanation:

1. If both columns are non-null, **and** r_closed > sfh_regeneratedon, then order by r_closed.
2. Otherwise, order by sfh_regeneratedon if not null, or (if sfh_regeneratedon is null) order by r_closed.

Recent SQL Server has GREATEST:

```
order by case GREATEST(col1, col2, col3 ) desc
```

(SQL Server handles NULL's like '*If one or more arguments aren't NULL, then NULL arguments are ignored during comparison. If all arguments are NULL, then GREATEST returns NULL.*' - which isn't according to the ANSI/ISO SQL standard.)

Comment: Great, firs one i used and it is working. also, another query i want to user third column as well as r_createdon. so can you share that also

Comment: Ask a new question. And use what you learnt here to have a go